# In printf ( " %.*f ", a, b ), what would be the result if 'a' is negative?

Tags: c, printf

Generally when we do something like:

```
printf ( " %.*f ", 2, 3.3 );
```

the precision width is being set to 2 and outputs **3.30**. But what if the width is given the negative value, e.g.

```
printf ( " %.*f ", -2, 3.3 );
```

The output is **3.300000** which means the default width is being used. So what exactly is this **-2** doing here ?

Comment: According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), it's ignored: *If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored.*

Comment: Huh. I got something completely different from http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf

Comment: Welp, http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/printf/ also says it's ignored.

Comment: Whenever you have a simple question like this why not just try it? Sites like http://codepad.org are good for this kind of thing.

Comment: @PaulR_ Dont you think these kind of small ( and simple to you ) doubts can only come when one does try it.

P.S. I have my own compiler where I do try these simple things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chris commented similarly above,

> A negative precision is taken as if the precision were omitted

Here's a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: §7.21.6.1/5 if anyone's interested (at least in the C11 one). I was just looking that up myself.

Answer (score 4):

> A negative precision is taken as if the precision were omitted.

Source: C99 7.19.6.1 (HTML version at http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#7.19.6.1)

Or from POSIX (more readable): http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html

Answer (score 2):

Late C11 standard draft says (7.21.6.1):

> A negative precision argument is taken as if the precision were omitted.

(Yes, it's for `fprintf`, and this is what the draft says of `printf` (7.21.6.3):)

> The printf function is equivalent to fprintf with the argument stdout interposed
>   before the arguments to printf.